# Вставка кастомного partialView на страничку MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть область в общей вьюхе. Внутри надо вставлять один или иной partialView. Как определить в контроллере какого типа partialView будет вставятся в наш View?

Comment: Покажите кусочки вашего кода, и опишите подробнее ситуацию: что такое "общая вьюха"? Это родительское view, которое имеет модель, или же это _Layout view, которое не имеет модели?

Comment: @Shad
Это родительское view, которое может иметь модель. 
Например ParentView имеет <div id="panel"> в который в зависимости от параметров запроса нужно вставлять результат или _ChildPartialView1, или _ChildPartialView2

Comment: @sss может я чего-то не  понял, но чем вас не устраивает такое: 

    public ActionResult MyAction(bool condition) 
    {
        return PartialView(b ? _ChildPartialView1 :   _ChildPartialView2); 
    }

Comment: @sss, добавьте в модель родительской view свойство, в которое записывайте в контроллере имя дочернего view, которое должно быть вставлено.

Comment: @DreamChild
Вариант, конечно. Но а что если у каждого партиала придется контроллер делать свой личный? 
@Shad
Это понятно, а как реализовать? 

И вот еще вопрос, если можно. 
Как при начальном открытии странички заполнять контйенер для аякс данных? Например, есть Ajax.BeginForm которая загружает свои данные при сабмите в див. Как сделать чтоб при первом открытии страницы (когда сабмита еще не было) в этот див попало дефолтное значение?

Comment: >Но а что если у каждого партиала придется контроллер делать свой личный?

а в чем проблема? И потом, не многовато чести для одного представления несколько контроллеров? Выглядит странно

Comment: @DreamChild
Возможно, до меня не доходит очевидное. Можете, пожалуйста, набросать пример с 
`public ActionResult MyAction(bool condition) 
{
    return PartialView(b ? _ChildPartialView1 :   _ChildPartialView2); 
}`

And it parent:
`public ActionResult MyAction(bool condition) 
{
    ViewBag.condition = condition;
    return View();
}`

И разметкой родителя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, я не очень понял всю суть проблемы, но по-моему, она тривиальна. Вот как это все может выглядеть в очень простом случае:

Основное представление:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(
        function() {
            $('#btnId').on('click',
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("PartialView")',
                        data: { condition: $('#viewCheckbox').is(':checked') },
                        success: 
                            function(data) { $('#partialViewDiv').html(data); }
                    });
                });
        });
</script>

<h2>MainView</h2>    
<div id="partialViewDiv"> </div>

@Html.CheckBox("viewCheckbox")
<input type="button" id="btnId" value="Render"/>
```

Как можно видеть, большую часть занимает многословный JS. 
Для этого представления в контроллере имеем очень простое действие:

```
public ActionResult MainView()
{
    return View();
}
```

Далее два еще более лаконичных partial view:

```
<h2>First PartialView</h2>
```

и

```
<h2>Second PartialView</h2>
```

и экшн:

```
public ActionResult PartialView(bool condition)
{
    return condition ? PartialView("PartialView") : PartialView("SecondPartialView");
}
```

Собственно, все. В зависимости от галочки на чекбоксе по нажатию на кнопку отображается то или иное представление

Comment: Все очень просто, да. Спасибо. 
А как вам такое решение, где имя партиала будет передаваться прямо в параметре и на страничке родительской:

   @if (ViewData["tabname"] != null)
   {
        @Html.Partial(ViewData["tabname"].ToString());
   }

Может есть лучший вариант?

Comment: выглядит жутковато если честно. И получается еще один лишний запрос на сервер

Comment: @DreamChild
Хм. А вот все-таки ваш пример не очень подходит. Ткк нужно иметь возможность генерировать страничку без аякса с заполненным контентом.
Например, по запросу ourpage?tab=first

Comment: ну и в чем проблема? Уберите аякс